# What do I use instead of Func1 when using RxJava2?

Tags: rx-java2

I am using a PublishSubject with RxJava and my code looked liked this

```
 mPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create()
                .map(new Func1<String, List<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<String> call(String s) {
                    return mRestClient.searchForCity(s);
                }
                })

                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

How do I do the same while using RxJava2, I tried using Function instead of Func1 but I get an error saying -  method map in class Observable cannot be applied to given types.

Comment: You should use [Function](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#functions), what's the type of mPublishSubject? show the code that you are trying with Function.

Comment: PublishSubject<String>, I am trying to fetch a list of strings ,when an input is passed on on mPublishSubject.

Answer (score 0):

As sources says:

```
public final <R> Observable<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) {
    ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(mapper, "mapper is null");
    return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(new ObservableMap<T, R>(this, mapper));
}
```

So you need a Function!
Or you can always use a lambda like: `s -> { return /*your data type*/; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `java.util.Function` via lambda syntax and define your PublishSubject type parameter beforehand so that your function's input parameter type becomes known:

```java
mPublishSubject = PublishSubject.<String>create()
   .map(s -> mRestClient.searchForCity(s))
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```